# Creating a 2D array in Javascript with the values as the product of the indices

Tags: javascript, xcode, visual-studio-code

I got a problem which says:

Write a program which takes 2 digits, X,Y as input and generates a 2-dimensional array. The element value in the i-th row and j-th column of the array should be i*j.
Note: i=0,1.., X-1; j=0,1,¡­Y-1.
Example
Suppose the following inputs are given to the program:
3,5
Then, the output of the program should be:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]

.....

I write the following code for it:

```
var main=[]
function array(x,y){
    var n=x
    while(n<0){
        main.push([0])
        n-=1
    }

    for(let i=0 ; i<x ; i+=1){
        for (let j=0 ; j=y ; j+=1){
            main[i].push(i*j)
        }
        main[i].shift()
    }
    return main
}
console.log(array(2,2))
```

but I am getting an error in running it in VScode. please guide me

Comment: sir this code is not running , occurring an error

Comment: please guide me , i am very much tensed

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (/index.js:15)

Comment: this is the error

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to push to the array. You can write directly to the `x` and `y` index of the target array, as long as `array[x]` itself is an array.

What you can do is for each `x` of `width` (the first array level) you can create an array of size `y` and then write `x*y` values into its elements.

There's probably a faster way of doing this but I find the following to be the most readable.

```
function make2DArray(width, height) {
  const array = Array(width);
  for (let x=0; x<width; x++){
    array[x] = Array(height);
    for (let y=0; y<height; y++){
      array[x][y] = x*y;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: yes , it works , thanks 

please tell me , what does "Array()" do ?

Comment: `Array(n)` will create an array that has a `length` of `n`, but no values. [MDN Web Docs: Array- Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir ,